# Bash script for looping through some files with name alterations

Tags: linux, bash, file, loops

How to create a bash script to loop through some files and perform few actions that involves name alterations:

find all index.html files in all subdirectories except components/* and process each file like:

```
mv dir1/index.html dir1/index_dev.html
vulcanize -o dir1/index.html dir1/index_dev.html

mv dir2/index.html dir2/index_dev.html
vulcanize -o dir2/index.html dir2/index_dev.html
...
```

Thanks

Comment: you didn't even try to manually run your commands, if you were, you would have seen some 'file not found' error. Cause after doing `mv` index.html will not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have:

```
for FILE in */index.html; do
    [[ $FILE == components/index.html ]] && continue  ## Skip.
    mv "$FILE" "${FILE%.html}"_dev.html
done
```